Upper Bound on Average Number of Divisiors
I am working with Iwaniec's "Fourier coefficients of modular forms of half-integral weight". For the first estimate on p.397 he seems to have used
$$
\sum \limits _{B<b\leq 2B} \tau(b)b^{1/2} \ll B^{3/2},
$$
where $\tau(b)$ denotes the number of divisors of $b$. The best bound to this sum I was able to find so far is $B^{3/2}\log(B)$ or $B^{3/2+\varepsilon}$. I used the known bound for the average number of divisors
$$
\sum _{1\leq b\leq x} \tau(b) = x\log x + (2\gamma-1)x + \mathcal{O}(x^{1/2}).
$$
More precisely, I extracted $b^{1/2}\leq (2B)^{1/2}$ and split the sum into to sums ranging over $1\leq b \leq 2B$ and $1\leq b \leq B$ to apply the aforementioned bound. However, I cannot seem to get rid of the log term. Any help would be grately appreciated.

The correct upper bound should be of size $B^{3/2} \log B$.

The claim that
$$ \sum \limits _{B<b\leq 2B} \tau(b)b^{1/2} \ll B^{3/2} $$
is not true. By partial summation we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \leq X} \tau(n) \sqrt{n} &=
T(X) \sqrt{X} + O(1) - \frac{1}{2} \int_1^X \frac{T(t)}{\sqrt{t}} dt \\
&= X^{3/2} \log X + c X^{3/2} + O(X) - (\tfrac{1}{3} X^{3/2} \log X + \tfrac{1}{9} X^{3/2} + O(X)) \\
&\sim \tfrac{2}{3} X^{3/2} \log X.
\end{align}
Here, I've used
\begin{equation}
T(X) = X \log X + cX + O(\sqrt{X}),
\end{equation}
as you've given.
In particular, this shows that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{B < b \leq 2B} \tau(b) b^{1/2}
\sim \tfrac{2}{3} (2B)^{3/2} \log (2B) - \tfrac{2}{3} B^{3/2} \log B
\asymp B^{3/2} \log B.
\end{equation}

Thank you, this is really helpful. However, I found out that Iwaniec must have considered the partial sum over only those b between B and 2B with odd parity. I believe that this does not impact the bound - could someone verify or refute that?
